# Where to unsubscribe events in a Xamarin.Forms Entry?

Tags: c#, events, xamarin.forms

I have a custom entry inheriting from Xamarin.Forms Entry to add a CompletedCommand Property. For that, I subscribe to the Completed Event of the Xamarin.Forms Entry in the constructor and invoke the bindable Property Command.

My Question is, is it necessary to unsubscribe? If so, where is a good place to do that?

```
public class Entry : Xamarin.Forms.Entry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CompletedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                     propertyName: nameof(CompletedCommand),
                                                     returnType: typeof(ICommand),
                                                     declaringType: typeof(Entry),
                                                     defaultValue: null,
                                                     defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    /// <summary>
    /// The Command to execute when this entry is completed (Enter pressed).
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CompletedCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CompletedCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CompletedCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public Entry() : base()
    {
        Completed += Entry_Completed;
    }

    private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompletedCommand?.Execute(CompletedCommandParameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "xamarin unsubscribe events" gave lots of interesting results. I feel like, if possible, you want to use an EventToCommandBehavior (part of xamarin toolkit i believe?) to avoid using events. But if you can't do that, unsubscribing might be unnecessary but still a best practice.

Source: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/188

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I wanted to avoid EventToCommandBehavior, I find it easier in useage to have "Completed" directly as a bindable property.